# How to include total rows returned as a column value?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, max, rownum

**Oracle 11g**

I'd like to include max(rownum) as a new column to get the desired results. In essence, I'd like add the results from this *QueryA* as a new column to *QueryB.*  When I include max(rownum) in QueryB I get a 'not a single-group function. Nor does QueryB work when I group by cola or rownum.

**QueryA**

```
with data_row as
(
select 1 as col_a from dual union all
select 2 as col_a from dual union all 
select 3 as col_a from dual )
select max(rownum) as max_row from data_row
```

**QueryB**

```
with data_row as
( select 1 as col_a from dual union all
  select 2 as col_a from dual union all
  select 3 as col_a from dual)
select col_a, rownum from data_row
```

**Desired Result**

```
Col_a    Rownum   MaxRowNum
--------------------------------
1          1       3
2          2       3
3          3       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the analytic form of the `count` function

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with data_row as (
  2    select 1 as colA from dual union all
  3    select 2 as cola from dual union all
  4    select 3 as cola from dual
  5  )
  6  select colA, rownum, count(*) over () cnt
  7*   from data_row
SQL> /

      COLA     ROWNUM        CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          3
         2          2          3
         3          3          3
```

Comment: @PM77-1 - Why would we need to use `SUM`?  And what do you believe we would need to `SUM`?  It sounds like the goal is to determine the number of rows in the result set so `COUNT` seems like a sensible choice.

Comment: I was thinking about **MAX** actually - but even this is wrong.  Please disregard my comment.